# Lavalink music bot doesn't want to play music

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

## The music bot refuses to play music.It gives the following errors after the code, I will be glad for any help.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVZjW.png)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from lavalink import Lavalink

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.music = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")

bot.lavalink = Lavalink(bot)
bot.lavalink.add_node('localhost', 2333, 'youshallnotpass', 'na', 'music-node')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    # Подключаем бота к голосовому каналу
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=channel, self_mute=False, self_deaf=False)

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    # Воспроизведение музыки
    player = bot.lavalink.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)

    if not player.is_connected:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=channel, self_mute=False, self_deaf=False)

    tracks = await bot.lavalink.get_tracks(query)

    if not tracks:
        return await ctx.send('Треки не найдены')

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Выберите трек для воспроизведения", color=0x00ff00)

    for i, track in enumerate(tracks, start=1):
        embed.add_field(name=f'{i}. {track["info"]["title"]}', value=f'Duration: {track["info"]["length"] // 1000}s')

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content.isdigit()

    response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

    track = tracks[int(response.content) - 1]

    if not player.is_playing:
        player.store('channel', ctx.channel.id)
        await bot.lavalink.connect(ctx.guild.id, ctx.channel.id)
        await ctx.send('Подключено к голосовому каналу')

    player.add(requester=ctx.author.id, track=track)
    await ctx.send(f'Добавлено в очередь: {track["info"]["title"]}')

@bot.command()
async def skip(ctx):
    # Пропустить трек
    player = bot.lavalink.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)

    if not player.is_playing:
        return await ctx.send('Нет активного трека для пропуска')

    await ctx.send('Пропущено')
    player.skip()

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # Отключение бота от голосового канала, если все пользователи покинули канал
    if not member.bot and after.channel is None:
        guild_id = before.channel.guild.id
        player = bot.lavalink.player_manager.get(guild_id)

        if player.is_connected and not any(member.voice for member in after.channel.members):
            await bot.lavalink.disconnect(guild_id)
            await bot.lavalink._nodes['music-node'].destroy(guild_id)
            await player.destroy()

bot.run("token")
```

## ImportError: cannot import name 'Lavalink' from 'lavalink' (C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\lavalink_*init*_.py)

I have everything installed: lavalink.jar and so on Java 17

Comment: From https://github.com/Devoxin/Lavalink.py/blob/master/examples/music.py, you don't seem to need to import Lavalink.